# A question about Poisson Process: operating events from different sample spaces?

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

The following proof, that how to derive Poisson Distribution from a Poisson Process, is from my textbook, *Elementry Probability Theory*(Fourth Edition), written by Kai Lai Chung, Farid AitSahlia.

#### Proof

Define $T_j$ as interarrival time: $$P(T_j > t) = e^{- \alpha t}, t \ge 0$$ $\alpha$ is *intensity of the flow*.

Define $S_n$ as the waiting time until the *n*th arrival: $$S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n T_j$$

Define $N(t)$ as the total number of arrivals in the time interval $[0, t]$. By definition, we have $$\{ N(t) \ge n \} = \{ S_n \le t \}$$

Taking the difference of both sides in the above equations for $n$ and $n+1$, we obtain $$\{ N(t) = n \} = \{ S_n \le t \} - \{ S_{n+1} \le t \} = \{ S_n \le t < S_{n+1} \} (1)$$

Then, $$P\{ N(t) = n \} = P\{ S_n \le t \} - P\{ S_{n+1} \le t \} (2)$$

(Here omitted)

Finally, we get $P \{ S_n \le t\} = \int_0^t \frac{\alpha^n}{(n-1)!} u^{n-1} e^{- \alpha u}$(Erlang distribution), $P\{ N(t) = n \} = \frac{\alpha^n}{n!} t^n e^{-\alpha t}$(Poisson distribution).

#### Question

Later on is the rest of a complete proof of Poisson process to get Poisson Distribution. But here is my question! How to get equation $(2)$ from the equation $(1)$?

Recalling the definition of probability theory, event needs to exist as a subset of a sample space $\Omega$, and $P( \Omega ) = 1$. **Only events in a same sample space can be operated**. Looking at the probabilities in equation $(2)$, I think the events are in different sample space? $\{ N(t) = n \}$ in $\{ \text{variable n under certain t} \}$, $\{ S_n \le t \}$ in $\{ \text{variable t under certain n} \}$, $\{ S_n \le t \}$ in $\{ \text{variable t under certain n+1} \}$. I choose them by an important condition that $P(\Omega) = 1$.

**Why could I operate events in different sample spaces?**

Comment: **Every random variable involved**, namely, every $S_n$ and every $N(t)$ and every $T_j$, is defined on the same probability space. Dunno why you fathomed otherwise...

Comment: The events are in the same sample space. $\{N(t)\geq n\}$ abbreviates $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid N(t)(\omega)\geq n\}\subseteq\Omega$. Likewise $\{S_n\leq t\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid S_n(\omega)\leq t\}\subseteq\Omega$ where $N(t)(\omega)\geq n\iff S_n(\omega)\leq t$. So two descriptions of the same event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are in one sample space. The sample space is all the possible records. Trying to be more precise, each record can be represented by a sequence of nonnegative real numbers: $t_1, t_2, t_3, \cdots$

---

Thanks to @drhab and @Did to comment, they unraveled my confusion. But I've still writen this answer, because I hope every question has an answer.